# How can I create an album and save an image file to that album in Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, directory, save, gallery

Dear users of stack overflow,

I am a beginner in Android Studio and I am trying to create an app for taking a picture, cropping the picture, and saving the picture to a special folder created by the app, for the pictures taken with this app. And also I'd like the app to have a "Save Image" button, so that the user can preview the cropped image and save the image if he/she likes it.  So far, I've managed to compile a code that can take a picture and crop the picture (using uCrop). But there comes the problem that I couldn't resolve...

Since I am new to the platform and Java language, I don't really understand the logic behind the coding. Also, the online sources I've found are far from being descriptive, thus my problem is yet to be resolved.

I am attaching a copy of the code that I've written. Can anyone please tell me what to add to these codes to make my app create an album and store my images into it? Please remember that I am a beginner, I would really appreciate it if you can describe the code you write for an answer with small comments.

You can find the code below. Looking forward to hearing from you guys!

**Main Activity Code**

```
ImageView imageView;
Button btn;
Button gImage;
Uri gImageUri;
String currentPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.bt_Open);
    imageView=findViewById(R.id.gView);
    gImage=findViewById(R.id.saveImage);

}

public void onChooseaFile(View v){
    CropImage.activity().start(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            gImageUri = result.getUri();
            imageView.setImageURI(gImageUri);
                        }
        else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
            Exception e = result.getError();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Possible error is "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you consider to be an album?

Comment: Please start your code by posting the used intent to captire an image with the camera. And the one where you use CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for replying. I have an album called "Camera" in my Gallery app. Therefore I consider albums to have equivalent level of directory to "myfiles/images/camera". As for your second comment, as I have said I am merely a beginner. Can you please examplify what you mean?

Comment: So with creating an album you meancreating a folder for your images. Your onActivityResult() is triggered. This can only happen if you used something like startActivityForResult with where you use CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE. I think you will use createImageFile() there too.

Comment: @GöktürkCinel What result are you seeing?
Is this throwing an error, or is it just failing silently?
if you read through this Android doc it should give you the elements you need to do what you are trying;
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics
Bear in mind you may have to request permission from the user before writing to external storage. Here's some info on permissions; https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting